# Variable method calls - proper Ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, methods

I want to do this:

```
for u in users
  ['four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'].each do |n|
    win_streak = u."#{n}_win_streak"
  end
end
```

But am get this: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG.

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Object#send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999) method:

```
win_streak = u.send("#{n}_win_streak")
```